# How to use Talend tRESTClient component to send xml request with POST method

Tags: talend

I'm trying to use Talend studio 6.4.1 to call a REST API, the request body is xml and the method is POST, by using a tRESTClient component, the response is

[Error Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpv2a.png)

It seems that the problem is caused by wrong url, but by using the Postman, it works well.

The screenshot is as below:

[The job and tRESTClient component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7FyH.jpg)

and the input schema is like as below:
[The input schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jsb6.jpg)

I have search for this problem via Google and StackOverflow for a long time, but I can't find the reason, any suggestion would be very appreciated, thank you in advance. By the way, the 1.1.1.1 is not real IP I used, but just for privacy purpose.

Comment: Is your transactions column an xml document ? Could you try with a tREST component, by pasting an xml in the http body field and see what you get ?

Comment: @iMezouar Thanks for your reply. The 'transactions' column is an xml document, what do you mean a 'tREST component' , is it different from the 'tRESTClient' component ? And how could I pass an xml into the http body?

Comment: tREST works similar to tRESTClient, except that it doesn't take an input row. Just drop it onto the designer, and you'll find it has a field called HTTP Body (it appears when you select POST method). Please try it and let me know.

Comment: @iMezouar Thank you for your great suggestion, I have tried to use the tREST client with the whole request URL, and change the double quote to single quote in the xml content and it works fine now. But I still don't know why the tRESTClient component can't work well, and still need a way to to support dynamic XML input, which seems can't be supported by the tREST component. Could you help give me some other suggestions?